# How to find out docker deamon API URL using bash commands

Tags: python, docker

I'd like to find out 'Engine API URL' of docker deamon in order to connect to it from Pycharm. I'm running python code on Airflow where DAG executes BashOperator with docker command in it. What should I pass to BashOperator to get to know API URL. I tried 'docker inspect' but it didn't return anything what could bring me closer to the answer.

Comment: If it's not a platform-specific default, it will be in the environment variable `$DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: Not true. $DOCKER_HOST returns nothing. Checked where  'docker' command is recognized

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `docker-machine` isn't available, you can fetch the context of `docker` using the following script:

```sh
ENGINE_URL=$([ -n "$DOCKER_HOST" ] && echo $DOCKER_HOST || docker context inspect --format '{{ index .Endpoints.do
cker.Host }}' ${DOCKER_CONTEXT:-default});
```

The script returns the address from the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable if it exists or from the data of the active context.

ENGINE_URL will contain the address

```
echo $ENGINE_URL; # e.g., tcp://192.168.23.138:2376
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work
`[u184229@BIServer3 ~]$ ENGINE_URL=$([ -n "$DOCKER_HOST" ] && echo $DOCKER_HOST || docker context inspect --format '{{ index .Endpoints.docker.Host }}' ${DOCKER_CONTEXT:-default});`

`[u184229@BIServer3 ~]$ echo $ENGINE_URL`

`unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

The proper `ENGINE_HOST` in this case is `tcp://biserver3:2375`